# Does iOS provide built in text to speech support or any class like NSSpeechRecognizer?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

i have found many libraries like [flite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/) which can be be used, as in given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225521/text-to-speech-conversion), but I want to know if there is any Built-In class provided by iOS SDK similar to NSSpeechRecognizer provided in OS X.

Comment: this is a confusion question. the question indicates speech recognition in the description but is tagged with "text-to-speech" and also states "text to speech support" in title.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is no built in text-to-speech support in iOS 5 or 6 - you'll need to use a third party library. If you are using iOS 7 you're in luck.

There's a new class in iOS 7 called `AVSpeechSynthesizer` ([Apple's docs can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013447)). You can use this to perform text-to-speech. Here's a simple example:

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance 
                                speechUtteranceWithString:@"Hello world"];
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];

[synth speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Properties such as speed and voice type are set in the `AVSpeechUtterance`, rather than the synthesizer.

Comment: although still in beta iOS 7 is public now and includes the class `AVSpeechSynthesizer` that can be used for text-to-speech. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013447).

Comment: iOS7 is relased today so you can update your answer with your actual code.

Comment: NSSpeechRecognizer isn't for text-to-speech, it is for speech-to-text. What does iOS 7 have for speech recognition?

Comment: @Gerry - there is no public API for that. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812399/how-to-use-speech-recognition-inside-the-ios-sdk

Comment: this function not work in ios8. how to use this function in ios 8.

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't work in iOS 8. If you're having trouble using it, ask a question here or file a bug.