# Save text to audio file programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos

It's possible to save text as audio file as shown in screenshot. Now my question is that how to do the same programmatically.
[image]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSSpeechSynthesizer` does that job.

Say we have the property :

```
@property  NSSpeechSynthesizer *synth;
```

that we initialize like this:

```
synth = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice:nil];
```

we can do:

```
NSURL *saveURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Desktop/SpokenText.aiff" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
[synth startSpeakingString:@"A spoken short text" toURL:saveURL];
```

Before saving, we probably want to change the voice or the volume:

```
[synth setVolume:0.5f];
[synth setVoice:voiceID];
```

where the `value for volume` is expressed in floating-point units ranging from 0.0 through 1.0 and `voiceID` is a `voice identifier`.

To see all available voice identifiers:

```
NSArray *voiceIdentifiers = [NSSpeechSynthesizer availableVoices];
NSLog(@"%li %@",voiceIdentifiers.count,voiceIdentifiers);
```

Output on `OS X 10.10.3` with all voices installed:

```
101 (
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Agnes",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Albert",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Alex",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.alice.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.allison.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.alva.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.amelie.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.angelica.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.anna.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.audrey.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.aurelie.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.ava.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.BadNews",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Bahh",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Bells",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Boing",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Bruce",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Bubbles",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.carlos.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.carmit.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.catarina.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Cellos",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.cem.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.chantal.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.claire.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.damayanti.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.daniel.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Deranged",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.diego.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.ellen.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.ewa.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.federica.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.felipe.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.fiona.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Fred",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.GoodNews",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.henrik.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Hysterical",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.ioana.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.iveta.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.joana.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.jorge.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.juan.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Junior",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.kanya.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.karen.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.kate.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Kathy",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.katya.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.klara.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.kyoko.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.laura.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.lee.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.lekha.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.luca.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.luciana.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.magnus.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.mariska.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.markus.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.mei-jia.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.melina.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.milena.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.moira.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.monica.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.nicolas.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.nikos.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.nora.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.oliver.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.oskar.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.otoya.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.paola.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.paulina.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.petra.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Organ",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Princess",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Ralph",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.samantha.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.sara.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.satu.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.serena.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.sin-ji.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.soledad.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.susan.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.tarik.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.tessa.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.thomas.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.ting-ting.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.tom.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Trinoids",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.veena.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Vicki",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Victoria",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Whisper",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.xander.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.yannick.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.yelda.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.yuna.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.yuri.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Zarvox",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.zosia.premium",
    "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.zuzana.premium"
)
```

Comment: Have tried it     
bool b = [synthesizer startSpeakingString:@"I have started speaking" toURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Desktop"]]; returns true but can't find the file

Comment: Cool, thanks. I added the URL-creation also to the code so the answer is clearer.

Comment: Great! and is there any solution for iOS for the same case?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS 7 Apple provides the following API...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17465494/215748

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
…
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance 
                            speechUtteranceWithString:@"Hello world"];
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
[synth speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Comment: My question is to save as audio file instead of speak via speaker.  Rather I need mac support.

Comment: recording an audio is not a great idea

Comment: how do you conver is what my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75461/discussion-between-rahul-and-idev).